# Miui 9.2.5 installation via usb is temporarily restricted. How do I fix this?

Tags: android, miui

I have googled it all over and tried all the solutions answered to the similar questions such as:

1. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn off
   Miui Optimizations -> Restart
2. Turn on mobile data, not wifi and
   don't use any VPN
3. Security -> Permissions -> Gear Icon at top right corner -> Turn On "Install via USB"
4. Settings -> Additional Settings -> Developer options -> Turn On/Off "USB Debugging" -> Turn On "Install vis USB"

But nothing works. Can someone suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet? Turn off wifi and turn on mobile data and enable Install via USB